# Is there a way to call functions inside firebase API with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm creating a new thread because I didn't find solutions here.

I'm facing a problem with *javascript* in *ionic* in which I should call functions already defined by me inside a *firebase API*. Here is my situation:

```
change(val){
 firebase
 .auth()
 .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,val.old_password)
 .then(function(user) {
   firebase
     .auth()
     .currentUser.updatePassword(val.new_password)
     .then(function() {
       console.log("pass changed");
       ### here the function to show the message
     })
     .catch(function(err) {
       console.log("an error happend changing pass");
       ### here the function to show the message
     });
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
   console.log("a very bad error happend");
 });

}

passwordChanged(){
  this.alertCtrl.presentTimeAlert(
    "Password changed",
    "The process was successful",
    "",
    2
  );
}

passError(){
  this.alertCtrl.presentAlert(
    "Error",
    "An error occurred. \n Retry",
    "Okay"
  );
}
```

My goal is to show a message either if I changed the pass or I didn't. Given the fact that this function is async, I wanted to use **passwordChanged** and **passError** as "callback" but they are *undefined* inside firebase function scope. Actually all my variables and functions are *undefined* where I should show the message.

Knowing the fact that I'm using firebase library and it can be normal this behavior, there is some way in order to avoid this problem?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This article may be helpful [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: Thank you for this article, it is good to know that I can define functions from the backend. In this case it would be incorrect in the sense that the smartphone is doing all the process with firebase service and the message should pop out on the display. That's why I was looking for a method to use functions inside that scope

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. What happens if you replace `### here the function to show the message` with `passwordChanged()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
passwordChanged() {
    this.alertCtrl.presentTimeAlert(
      'Password changed',
      'The process was successful',
      '',
      2
    );
  }

  passError(changeErrors) {
    this.alertCtrl.presentAlert(
      'Error',
      'An error occurred. \n Retry',
      'Okay'
    );
  }

  async change(val) {
    const changeErrors = [];

    ///
    // Try to login
    const tryToLogIn = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, val.old_password)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('A very bad error happend', err);

        changeErrors.push(err);

        return null;
      });

    if (tryToLogIn) {
      ///
      // Try to update the password
      const updatePassword = await new Promise((res) => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(val.new_password)
          .then(() => { console.log('Password changed'); res(true); })
          .catch((err) => { console.error('An error happend changing pass', err); changeErrors.push(err); res(false); });
      });

      if (updatePassword) {
        // Password was updated
        passwordChanged();
      } else {
        // Password was not updated
        passError(changeErrors);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution fits perfectly my situation

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reach your goal by publishing a message with a event emitter, so you can use the results outside

Here a example

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// second page (listen for the user created event after. 
function is called)
    constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in. 
`events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Comment: This is a good system structure and I could use it in other cases. The problem is that, inside the firebase function (so after it updates the password), "this.event" will be undefined so it throws the undefined error. In my case, it would be the same as using "this.alertCtrl.presentTimeAlert"